# Select second higher value with Rank() function in PosgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datagrid

I tried this :

```
SELECT
code_nuance, nb_voix,
RANK () OVER ( ORDER BY nb_voix DESC) AS rank
FROM  election_2015.resultat_nuance_departement
WHERE rank = 2;
```

And same with alias :

```
SELECT
rnd.code_nuance, rnd.nb_voix,
RANK () OVER ( ORDER BY rnd.nb_voix DESC) AS rank
FROM  election_2015.resultat_nuance_departement rnd
WHERE rank = 2;
```

Rank is not recognized in the WHERE close.
It says "Rank doesn't exist"

Any one?

Any suggestions welcomed, ty !

Answer (score 0):

As with all other column aliases, you cannot use the alias in the `where` clause.  For this purpose a subquery is handy:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT rnd.code_nuance, rnd.nb_voix,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rnd.nb_voix DESC) AS rank
      FROM election_2015.resultat_nuance_departement rnd
     ) x
WHERE rank = 2;
```

If the values are all unique, you can also use `FETCH`:

```
select rnd.*
from election_2015.resultat_nuance_departement rnd
order by rnd.db_voix desc
offset 1 fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I failed on a simple SQL error :x

Answer (score 0):

[from the postgresql docs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST)

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but not in the WHERE or HAVING clauses; there you must write out the expression instead.

This is because WHERE clause is resolved before column aliases are considered.

Another solution could be using a subquery.